# How is it possible to see a column name from a different table within a subquery from different table?

Tags: sql

I was practicing a subqueries in sql  and all of a sudden i jumped into an unsual query which i never thought of could happen.
The question of my query is....

Write a query to display the average rate of Australian dollar,where the currency rate date is July 1 2005??

And the query was...

USE AdventureWorks2012

```
SELECT AverageRate FROM Sales.CurrencyRate
WHERE ToCurrencyCode='AUD' AND CurrencyRateDate IN 
                          (SELECT CurrencyRateDate FROM Sales.Currency
                           WHERE CurrencyRateDate='2005-07-01')
```

So,my question is how is it possible to get the column name "CurrencyRateDate" in the sub query when it is actually from the table "CurrencyRate"??

I know my query is not in the correct format as it should be.

I'm extremely sorry if my title doesn't make sense.If you guys can give any better please change it..

Thanks

Comment: did you check the columns in  `currency` table?

Comment: The subquery is selecting `CurrencyRateDate` from the *outer* query.

Comment: Oh,OK.  Thanks @ Blorgbeard

Comment: Your query will not answer the question you were given.  You were told to get an average and you are selecting *.  Plus, you don't need a sub-query.

Comment: Sorry,I forgot a column name "AverageRate".I hope now you get it.@ Dan Bracuk

Answer (score 1):

```
AND CurrencyRateDate IN 
 (SELECT CurrencyRateDate FROM Sales.Currency
  WHERE CurrencyRateDate='2005-07-01')
```

All the `CurrencyRateDate` references here point to the column from the outer query.

So for each row in the outer query, you are getting a list consisting of only that row's `CurrencyRateDate`, repeated once for every row in the `Sales.Currency` table (if the `CurrencyRateDate` of that row is `2005-07-01`, otherwise the list is empty).

Then you check whether the outer `CurrencyRateDate` value is in that list. Which it is, if and only if it's equal to `2005-07-01` (assuming there is at least one row in `Sales.Currency`).

So your query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT * FROM Sales.CurrencyRate
WHERE ToCurrencyCode='AUD' AND CurrencyRateDate='2005-07-01'
```